# Programa en java para calcular modas de una muestra

Tags: java

Tengo el código para calcular la moda de una muestra de población pero no sé qué hacer en caso de que sea una muestra de dos modas o más.

```
public static void getModa(double muestra[]) {

    int maximoNumRepeticiones= 0;
    double moda= 0;

    for(int i=0; i<muestra.length; i++)
    {
        int numRepeticiones= 0;
        for(int j=0; j<muestra.length; j++)
        {
            if(muestra[i]==muestra[j])
            {
                numRepeticiones++;
            }   //fin if
            if(numRepeticiones>maximoNumRepeticiones)
            {
                moda= muestra[i];
                maximoNumRepeticiones= numRepeticiones;
            }   //fin if
        }
    }   //fin for
    System.out.print(moda);
}   //fin getModa
```

Esto es lo que espero que haga: 
Entrada: `double muestra= new double {3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4}`
Salida: `moda= 3
              4`

Esto es lo que hace:
Entrada: `double muestra= new double {3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4}`
salida: `moda= 3`

Se supone que tengo dos modas: 3 y 4. Podría incluso tener más pero solo me muestra la primera.

Comment: Coloca el codigo de lo que has intentado hasta ahora y cual es el objetivo de tu programa

Comment: Y si tratas de encontrar la moda de todas las muestras de poblaciones, y a estos resultados le calculas la moda?

Comment: por favor lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor aceptada!

Comment: Podrias colocar un ejemplo de cuales serían las muestras y que resultado esperas???

Comment: Dos cosas: 1) Devuelve un resultado en lugar de usar `System.out.print` dentro del método, así es más sencillo de evaluar su funcionamiento. 2) En lugar de devolver 1 número, deberías devolver un arreglo de `int`, es decir un `int[]` con los valores de moda disponibles.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un ArrayList para agregar muestras, y con el siguiente método puedes usar el que ya tienes definido pero para que ahora te calcule la moda de una lista de muestras. Abajo te agrego otro método que es una prueba de este esquema que te propongo, y una liga a la API de ArrayList.

```
public static void getModas(java.util.ArrayList<double[]> listaDeMuestras) {

    if (listaDeMuestras != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i<listaDeMuestras.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("procesando una muestra");
            getModa(listaDeMuestras.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public static void prueba3Muestras() {

    double[] muestra1 = new double[] {3, 41, 3, 3, 5, 4, 4};
    double[] muestra2 = new double[] {23, 4, 83, 93, 5, 4, 4};
    double[] muestra3 = new double[] {93, 4, 3, 3, 55, 64, 4};

    java.util.ArrayList<double[]> lista = new java.util.ArrayList();

    lista.add(muestra1);
    lista.add(muestra2);
    lista.add(muestra3);

    getModas(lista);

}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: Aunque esta puede ser la solución a la pregunta sería bueno que explicaras un poco tu código para un mayor entendimiento del mismo, podrías leer [answer], saludos !

Comment: ya leí la liga que mandaste de como responder. Y no estoy seguro que falte algo. Son dos métodos muy sencillos. El que está preguntando debe poder investigar ArrayList si es que no la conoce, y le pueda sacar mejor provecho. De todas maneras gracias por la observación. Saludos.

Comment: Debes agregar una explicación del código de lo contrario esta respuesta no sería de ayuda a otros desarrolladores. De hecho es uno de los motivos de voto negativo en las respuestas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear un método el cual reciba como argumento un array.

dentro del método utilizas un Hashmap para ver cuantas veces se repite un dato dentro del array.
después recorres el Hashmap y verificas cual es el dato que más se repite.

por ultimo creas las muestras de población y llamas al metodo creado para saber la moda de cada una de ellas.

```
public static void ModaPoblacion(int vector[]){
     
    HashMap <Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap();
   
    int repetido = 0, numMax = -1,repetidoCon = 0;
   
    for (int i : vector) {
        if (map.containsKey(i)) {
          repetido =  map.get(i);
          map.put(i, ++repetido); 
        } else{
            map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }
     
    for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> e : map.entrySet()) {
        if (repetidoCon < e.getValue()) {
            repetidoCon = e.getValue();
            numMax = e.getKey();
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("la moda en la población es  " +   numMax);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int PoblacionA[] = {14,20,20,40,50,60,60,60};
    int PoblacionB[] = {10,10,10,10,10,10,60,60};
    int PoblacionC[] = {14,20,20,20,20,20,60,60};
     
    ModaPoblacion(PoblacionA);
}
```