# Número que más se repite en una matriz en java

Tags: java

Estoy intentando realizar un ejercicio el cual me permita ver cuál es el elemento que más se repite de una matriz en java, el problema es que solo puedo comparar una posición de la matriz con las demás.
Acá esta mi código.

```
     int Matriz[][] = {{20,40,8},{40,40,8},{40,120,20}};

     int Repetido = 0;
     
     int numero = 0;
     
     int contadorA = 0 , contadorB = 0 ;
    
     for (int i = 0; i < Matriz.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[i].length; j++) {
                                  
              
            if ( Matriz[i][j] == Matriz[0][1] ) {
                 
                Repetido++;
                 
                numero =  Matriz[i][j];
       
                
            }

        }
         
    }
     
    
      System.out.println("el número que mas veces se repite es: " + numero + " y se repite " + Repetido + " veces " );
```

Comment: primero habria que contar cuantas veces aparece un numero en la matriz ,despues comparar esas cantidades para obtener el que mas repite

Comment: Revisa el siguiente link donde hallan la [moda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97417/193364) de un arreglo, solo faltaría que tu matriz conviertas a un arreglo unidimensional

Comment: Muchas gracias mi bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de lo que requieres.

Se realiza un ciclo, para sumar el numero de ocurrencias por numero y posterior se recorre un Hashmap, para conseguir el que mas veces se repite.

```
package stacoverflow;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author Israel Ramos
 */
public class Maximo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int Matriz[][] = {{20, 40, 8}, {40, 40, 8}, {40, 120, 20}};

        int repetidoCont = 0;
        int numeroMax =-1;

        int repetido = 0;

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> mapa = new HashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matriz[i].length; j++) {

                if (mapa.containsKey(Matriz[i][j])) {
                    repetido = (int) mapa.get(Matriz[i][j]);
                    mapa.put(Matriz[i][j], ++repetido);
                } else {
                    mapa.put(Matriz[i][j], 1);
                }
            }
        }

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> e : mapa.entrySet()) {
    
            if(repetidoCont < e.getValue())
            {
               numeroMax = e.getKey();
               repetidoCont = e.getValue();
            }


        }
    

    System.out.println ("el número que mas veces se repite es: " + numeroMax + " y se repite " + repetidoCont + " veces ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, me podrías explicar como funciona el Hashmap si no es mucha molestia y gracias de nuevo.

Comment: El Hashmap es un tipo de objeto que las características que aprovechamos para el ejercicio que se resolvió son:

1.- Se conforma de una llave y un valor, por lo que realizamos el conteo de todos los diferentes valores que venían en el array, en un solo ciclo.
2.- Las llaves no se pueden repetir, por eso se validaba que no existiera la llave para ingresarla con valor de 1 o que existiera y del valor anterior, le sumábamos 1.

Hay muchas maneras de resolver el ejercicio.